# Sync data from remote api and save it to my localdb

Tags: api, entity-framework-core, synchronization, bulkinsert, httpclientfactory

I want to sync data from remote api! something like 1M record! but the whole process talks about 5Mins.
as a user experience, that's very bad thing to do! I want the whole process takes less than 1S!
I mainly use .net core web api 6.0 with SQLite, EF Core!

I search a lot and I used `BulkInsert`! and `BlukSaveChangesAsync` and same it talks a long time!
Same it's very bad user experience. I tried the following commented solutions and same problem! I want to make it very fast! as the user! does not feel that there is sync in background or thow.

Note: also I stopped all indexes while inserting the data, to make the process faster! and same problem.

Note: My app is `Monolithic`.
I know I can use something like `Azure function` but that would be considered as over engineering.
I want the simpliest way to solve this! I searched a lot in YouTube, GitHub and Stack overflow and I found nothing that would help me as I wish.

Note: I'm writing the data in two tables!
first table: contains only 5 rows.
second table: contains 3 rows.

`

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<DatumEntity>> SyncCities()
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Cities");
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(
            "API_KEY_WITH_SOME_CREDS");

        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using var contentStream =
                await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Result>(contentStream);

            var datums = result!.Data;

            if (datums.Any())
            {
                //First solution
                //_context.Datums.AddRange(datums);
                //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                //second solution
                //await _context.BulkInsertAsync(datums);
                //await _context.BulkSaveChangesAsync();

                //Thread solution
                //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async delegate
                //{
                //    _context.Datums.AddRange(datums);
                //    await _context.BulkSaveChangesAsync();
                //});
            }

            return datums;
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<DatumEntity>();
    }
```

Tried: I tried bulkInsert! tried ThreadPool!stopped all indexes! I tried a lot of things. and nothing helped me as I tought!
I want the whole process takes less than 1S as the user does not move away from the application! because the bad user experience.

Comment: I think it is not possible. I can believe in 10-20 seconds.

Comment: Totally agree with your opinion, but let's see the experts suggestions.

Comment: Just test by yourself. BulkCopy for Sqlite is possible only via multiple inserts in one batch. You can do that approx for 1000 records  in one batch. Multi threading will not help. I know only big paid NewSql databases with cluster with ten or more nodes, which claim that they can handle half million records in one second. What you can do: create background job which inserts records in background.

Comment: Also check this extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), it has fast `BulkCopy` method. Note that I'm maintainer of this project.

Comment: Please tell me more about the database that would talk 1S! or how to make it as a background job! + the database for me is not a big deal! I can replace it with SQLServer, PostgreSQL, MySQL...etc

Comment: For example [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io) for background jobs. As database, for example [Singlestore](https://www.singlestore.com)

Comment: first time to hear about this db + yup someone tolled me that it's gonna be as a background job! and he tolled me to use someting like Hangfire or RabbitMQ + how? I would you mind provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ThreadPool solved the issue for me:

```
 if (datums.Any())
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async _ =>
            {
                using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var context = scope.ServiceProvider
                        .GetRequiredService<CitiesDbContext>();

                    context.Datums.AddRange(datums);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                };
            });
        }
```

Comment: So question was, how to create background task?

Comment: No exactly, it was a bout the fastest way to sync data! and that's the best solution helped me!, do you got another suggestions?